# How I add values in a list I am using as the parameter for a function?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to understand these instructions.

1. Set up a new function in your main program file named “summer” that takes a list as a parameter and returns a value we will determine in the next steps.
2. In the “summer” function, set up a loop that uses a counter variable named “n” that will take on the values 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12.
3. Each time through the loop, you are to call your “powerval” function from the “mymath” module passing as parameters item “n” and “n+1” from the list of data passed into “summer”. Add up all these values and return the final result to the caller.

So far I have:

```
def summer(list):
    for n in range(0,13,2):
        value=powerval(n,n+1)
```

After that I am lost.  How do i perform step 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add them up:

```
from mymath import powerval

def summer(lst):
    total = 0

    for n in range(0, 13, 2):
        total += powerval(lst[n], lst[n + 1])

    return total
```

I'm not sure where you use `lst` (I renamed `list` to `lst`, as `list` is a built-in function), so I'm guessing you're trying to get the `n`th and `n + 1`th elements from that list.

Comment: “powerval” function from the “mymath” module

Comment: @Gerrat: Is there more to that sentence?

Answer (score 4):

You add them up:

```
from mymath import powerval

def summer(somelist):
    sum = 0
    for n in range(0, 13, 2):
        sum += powerval(somelist[n], somelist[n + 1])
    return sum
```

So the return value of `powerval()` is added to the total sum so far, which was started at 0. You do need to pass in the `somelist[n]` and `somelist[n + 1]` values, not the indices themselves.

Comment: @Gerrat: I think we can assume that there is a `from mymath import powerval` line somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sum` method to accomplish this in a very fashionable way :)

```
def summer(myList):
    return sum(powerval(myList[n], myList[n+1]) for n in range(0, 13, 2))
```

This is also the fastest way.

PS: It's not a good idea to name you list "list", bacause that's a reserved name in python. That's why I have renamed it to myList in the example above.